# Logstash stops parsing logs at the end of the day

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logback, elastic-stack

I have this `logback` config

```
<appender name="STASH" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>my.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/my-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>
```

And I have `logstash` service which the read this file and send to `elasticsearch`.

All work fine. `logstash` parse my logs and send to `elasticsearch` and I can read it in `kibana`. But when I come to work the next day - I see that there are no logs. In file I have logs but in `elasticsearch` - not. I restart `logstash` and logs appear. Perhaps as at the end of the day the file is moved to the archive(`SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy`) and the logs are written to the new file - does the `logstash` not understand this? how to solve it?

**EDIT**

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/MyServer/my.log"
        codec => "json"
        type => "my"
    }
}

output {
    if [type]=="my" {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
             index => "my-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your logstash configuration?

Comment: @ alpert I add config